# generate Pseudo-Noise sequence in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have question about adding Pseudo-Noise sequence.

How can I add PN-sequence as a matrix or a vector with specific size?

Comment: Did you search in the MathWorks documentation page? Did you Google your question title? For me, both provided what seemed to be very relevant answers.

Comment: I searched in MathWorks , but I didn't search in google.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/search.html?qdoc=generate+Pseudo-Noise+sequence&submitsearch=

Comment: Checkout this question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/408086/103936

Comment: I've pointed you to some questions that you might find helpful. There are many, many more similar questions here. Please use the search function at the top of the page, or use Google, to find other relevant questions.